# How to update nodejs on a docker container ? Linux Debian

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, debian, docker-container

I would like to update nodejs but how to update nodejs on a docker container in a debian 10 ?

My dockerfile : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK4rD.jpg

I saw I need to update the dockerfile with the version but I got an error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rACl0.jpg

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: Please don't paste images, but paste the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just add another `FROM` line (except multi-stage builds). Each image can only have one base image that is defined using `FROM`.

There are different possible approaches to combine components from two images:

1. You update the base image (if you are the author of the base image, i.e. `moiamond/docker-ffmpeg-base-debian`) to your needs
2. You run the necessary commands in your Dockerfile to install/update the nodejs version you want to have (might be tricky if the image is very old and there is no up-to-date node version available as package).
3. You use a different base image, e.g. an image that contains the node version you want to use and install ffmpeg and other components that are contained in `moiamond/docker-ffmpeg-base-debian` via your Dockerfile.

Comment: I no longer use ffmpeg so I delete the line and I go an error on the CI/CD jobs gitlab.
`Pull complete
Pull complete
Digest: shakey
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:18.8.0-buster
 ---> 
Step 2/5 : COPY --from=0 / /
invalid from flag value 0: refers to current build stage
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

Comment: The `--from=0` is invalid. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just delete the first line.